# Trying to filter a pivot table for each tab and then paste the contents to that tab

Tags: vba, excel

As the title suggests I am working through building a report for which I have a slicer where the user can select the companies and then run a macro to create tabs with names from that list of companies and then filter the pivot tables and copy the information for each company into its corresponding tab.

My code may be inefficient I apologize I've been working on this for a while though. It is now telling me that I need a For statement before I can have my next. Am I shoving too much into this? Am I just a downright mess of code at this point?

Sub fillTabs()

For i = 1 To Sheets.Count

```
With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Search key").Sheets(i).Name = True
Range(A5, I10).Copy
Worksheets("sheet2").Range(A5, I20).Copy Worksheets("Sheet(i)").Range("A1")
```

Next i

End Sub

Thank you so much in advance! I'm a bit alone in the VBA world and don't have much for mentors on this particular language.

Comment: There is no correlation between the code you've provided and what you describe you want to achieve in your post. Can you post a screen-shot of your `PivotTable` and describe from which `PivotField` you want to build the excel sheets for each company

Answer (score 0):

The code isn't formatted properly in the question, but from a glance it looks like you might be missing the 'End With' statement to close off your With block before your 'Next i' statement.

[MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx)